# Weka Find Database Util Properties But Throwing Driver Not Found

Tags: mysql, maven, jdbc, weka

I build a simple weka application using Weka 3.7.13 dev version using MAVEN. I have initialise the `pom.xml` function to get weka library from the repository.

i want to run a simple clustering algorithm using weka, and connecting it to MySQL database. As per documentation, the weka need to have a `DatabaseUtil.props` file which contains it's jdbc driver. I have setup that.

This is my project structure:

[image]

I can retrieve the DatabaseUtils.props using my code below. But somehow the weka itself cannot recognise the `jdbc:Url and driver` name which i already configure inside.

`DatabaseUtil.props` file:

```
# JDBC driver (comma-separated list)
jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# database URL
jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/datamining
```

Java code which i trigger the Weka module:

```
public void dm(){
        int cluster = 4;
        InstanceQuery clusterQuery = null;
        try{            
            //file reader of database utilities properties
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File fileProps = new File(classLoader.getResource("DatabaseUtils.props").getFile());

            //setup the data preparation functionality then connect to database
            clusterQuery = new InstanceQuery();
                clusterQuery.setUsername("test");
                clusterQuery.setPassword("test");
                clusterQuery.setQuery("SELECT * FROM TEMP_KMEANS");
                clusterQuery.setCustomPropsFile(fileProps);
```

But when executed the function returning error: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:idb=experiments.prp`

It seems that the `DatabaseUtils.props` file cannot override the default driver value `jdbc:idb=experiments.prp`

Any ideas why this is throwing?

Any feedback and answer much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I created a DatabaseUtils.props file in the src / main / resources folder and wrote the following code. It worked for me, I'm using weka 3.8.0.

```
        File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("DatabaseUtils.props").toURI());


        InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();

        query.setCustomPropsFile(file);
        query.setUsername(MYSQL_USER);
        query.setPassword(MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        query.setQuery("select * from Action");

        instances = query.retrieveInstances();

        System.out.println(instances.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/experiment/InstanceQuery.html) says *"These may be changed by creating a java properties file called DatabaseUtils.props in user.home or the current directory"*. Your properties file does not match those requirements (a properties file in a jar is not on the filesystem). See also Chapter 14 of the [Weka manual](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/weka/WekaManual-3-7-13.pdf?download).

An alternative solution is to set the URL in code using [`setDatabaseURL`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.html#setDatabaseURL(java.lang.String)). As long as the JDBC driver is on the classpath this should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer about this. As i use the Weka as maven project for referring as subsidiary java EE project it seems i cannot change the `DatabaseUtils.props` in the weka.jar without opening the jar and change the file inside. I try to reference to `DatabaseUtils.props` in another resource folder. But changing this database utils inside the weka.jar will impact the project environment itself. Any ideas?

Comment: @randytan How I read the documentation, the file needs to be on the file system in the current directory or the user home folder (of the user executing the process), not part of any jar (which is where resources normally end up).

Comment: understood Mark, so i don't have any other options except opening the weka jar and change the properties file directly.